# Authentication, jwt, refresh token - where to store, why and how to not break request when access token expires

Tags: javascript, authentication, jwt, token, refresh-token

I am trying to understand authentication architecture with use of json web token. Despite my research there are still few areas where I am unsure about possible implementation.

I have seen that good practice is to use access token along with refresh token. Let's suppose I am going to keep access token in a cookie (http only etc.) to be able to give secure access to content requested not only from js but by web browser itself.

Now, where to store refresh token on client. My intent is to avoid forcing user to re-login each time he visits site so in-memory solution is not possible. Thus cookie or some sort of browser local storage/db.
If it is cookie it would be sent with every request, which I could imagine is not best from security point of view. If it is in local storage (from what I've heard) is not secure either.

Apart that I do not know how to solve the flow problem. Let me explain on an example:

Let's say that server gets request for some data and with access token and it turns out token expired. Now server must take (if it is there already in cookie) refresh token or ask for it and send new pair of tokens. The problem is, that original request is lost and it would have to be renewed from client side. So operation is unsuccessful and the smooth flow is broken from user point of view or it must be automated and handled silently but I find it not so easy to provide such functionality. How such problems are solved?
For instance with basic auth there is no such problem at all because browser automatically display (or send) auth data and goes back to original request.

And one more question about refresh token. If it is used just to be able to store it in DB in backend and by this have possibility to log-out user, why not store just access token in DB and read it from there only after it expired (I could even track additional expiration time by storing that data in DB). Then we could treat such access token as refresh token i.e. on that basis generate new one.